# How can I calculate walk and cycle times with OSMNX?

Tags: routes, osmnx

I been trying to calculate the distance and time of walking and cycling networks.

Apparently for calculating the travel times is always considered the maximun speed (for cars). So if a walk or cycle network has some primary/secondary.. car streets with a maximun speed of 50km/h or 30km/h a pedestrian or cyclist traveling through this streets would travel at a car speed aswell.

This is the way to imput speeds and travel times to segments according to the documentation and this [guide: routing-speed-time](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb)

```
G= ox.add_edge_speeds(G, hwy_speeds)
G= ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)
```

**hwy_speeds** is an imputer for missing values only. Been trying to replace all the speeds to 4km/h withuot success. Another idea was to convert the graph to a geodataframe, replace the maxspeeds and then back to graph.
I would appreciate some help, maybe I'm missing something. Thanks.

**Edit**
This is working example returning a 5 minutes walk for a 3 kilometer route:

```
import osmnx as ox

place = {"city": "kreuzberg", "country": "germany"}
boundary = ox.geocode_to_gdf(place)

G = ox.graph_from_polygon(boundary ['geometry'][0], 
network_type="walk", simplify=True)

x1 = 13.429755712125107 
y1 = 52.501651988374334
x2 = 13.379465339856976 
y2 = 52.485907177089004

orig = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, X=x1, Y=y1)
dest = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, X=x2, Y=y2)

route = ox.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight="travel_time")

G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)

route_time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, route, "travel_time")))
route_length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, route, "length")))
```

**Result:**

```
print("Route time: {} seconds, route length: {} meters".format(route_time/60, route_length))

>>> Route time: 5,283 minutes, route length: 3428 meters
```

This is around 38km/h. (that's maybe too fast even for a car?)
Didn't find in the documetation, how to specify speeds for segments that are actually not based on *'maximun speed'* tag

This is the **workaround** I will be using in case there's not an implemented method for calculating times with walking speeds (3-4km/h) and cycling speeds (14-18hm/h)

```
gdf = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
gdf[1]['maxspeed'] = 4
G = ox.graph_from_gdfs(gdf[0], gdf[1])
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete, minimal code snippet to exactly reproduce your issue. Your code snippet here should be *minimal* so it doesn't contain extraneous code or data unrelated to your specific problem and it should be *complete* so we can independently run it from top to bottom by copying/pasting it into a Python interpreter. That means all imports and all variables must be defined. If you're unsure how to create a good reproducible example, read [this guide](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports).

Comment: Hi @gboeing thanks a lot for your fast answer and your advice. Actually I will be using this way to debug my own code. That I tend to make things overcomplicated and actually it's much easier to test on a 'minimal' and 'complete' code. Thanks for the advice.
I added to the question, the reprodusable problem, and the workaround I found so far.

Comment: @gboeing, should i propose this as a feature?

Comment: Propose what as a feature?